# How to correctly send base64 encoded document from express to the client and initiate download?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flask, base64

I have a system with 3 applications.

1. React client for frontend
2. Flask backend for API
3. Node application for generating a word document (docx)

The backend flask application essentially acts as a proxy for all API requests. The client will send a request to an end-point in the backend that in turn will make a request to the express app.

The express application generates a Word doc like so:

```
  // http://localhost:4000/word-export
  Packer.toBase64String(doc)
    .then(resp => {
      const fileContents = Buffer.from(resp, 'base64');
      res.send(fileContents);
    })
    .catch(error => res.send('error'));
```

My Flask endpoint logic looks like:

```
    // http://localhost:5000/api/export
    response = requests.get(
        'http://localhost:4000/word-export', headers=headers, json=json_data)

    response = make_response(response.content)

    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/msword')
    # response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='doc.docx')

    return response
```

I need to be able to download this document from the client. How can I do this, or how should I decode the base64 string? Everything I have tried so far has failed.

Answer (score -1):

for sending docx file to browser use `toBlob()` method instead of using `toBase64String()` method and again converting to buffer. 
As per the doc at [this location](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/packers?id=version-5)

```
packer.toBlob(doc).then((blob) => {
    // saveAs from FileSaver will download the file
      saveAs(blob);
});
```

and if you are creating a docx file the mime type should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

you can refer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)